# How to print numbers in the following pattern with .NET

Tags: c#, string

I have a program in C# that takes an integer argument from the command line and prints number patterns from 1 to that number in the format below for a number like 5.

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

You can see that for each number, that number is printed the same time as itself, like for three it’s been printed on a single line three times, and so and so forth.

I have tried to develop a function that multiplies an integer with a string with `String.Concat(string param, int n)` and returns that string to another function with a loop that prints the expected output to terminal.

My code prints like below:

```
11
22
33
44
55
```

For a sample integer input like 5.

What am I doing wrong and what should I do to correct my loop so it gives me the expected output?

***Code***

```
static string MakeALine(int k){
    // All this function does is to convert the
    // integer argument to a string and multiply
    // it with itself and returns it
    return String.Concat(k.ToString,k);
}

// The function below contains a loop that should
// invoke the make a line correctly to achieve
// the desired output above
static string MakeLines(int arg){
    // The argument is the command line argument supplied
    string outp = "";
    // I have a problem in the loop below. How can I fix it?
    for(int k=1; k<=arg; k++){
        // Call makeALine and pass k as argument and append to the return string
        outp += MakeALine(k) + "\n";
    }
    return outp;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use [`new String(char,int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-string-ctor(system-char-system-int32))?

Comment: Where should I apply that, in the loop?

Comment: the first step in debugging is indenting your code

Comment: @Fildor, am trying to convert the integer to char using `new String(char.Parse(k.ToString(),k));` Compiler reports an error that cannot convert from char to a pointer of char

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xjiIMt or https://dotnetfiddle.net/TTBEg0

Comment: in the method `MakeALine()` you need to concate `k` with itself `k` times. You're actually concating it only twice

Comment: @Cid, debugged that.

Comment: @Fildor I tend to disagree. Although it will work and in production this is the way to go, the goal of this exercise is to train about using loops

Comment: There _is_ a loop @Cid , of course: you could use two loops ...

Comment: I should have said : nested loops

Comment: I used `new String(char, int count)` in the first function and maintained the way am invoking it from the second method and it works, Thanks everyone for your time and effort

Comment: @Cid, granted. That may be the case, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `MakeALine` method. You actually concat the number with itself, so for input `1` you actually get `"1" + "1"`.

Instead you should repeat the string representation of your number `k` times. For this you can use `Enumerable.Repeat` in the following way:

```
static string MakeALine(int k)
{
    return String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(k.ToString(),k));
}
```

Comment: Or you can make it simple and readable by just using two nested for loops.

Comment: That is why I was wondering why am getting an exception when using `new String(char m, int k)`, when you pass in a number like `15`, it won't work as the compier will throw `string must be exactly one character long`

Comment: @PubliusFlaviusTiberius An upper bound is part of the requirements which should always be mentioned in the question. I for example, didn't take any input > 9 as a reasonable input.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```cs
private static string makeLines(int k)
{
    string outPut = "";
    for(int i = 1 ; i < k+1 ; i++)
    {
        outPut += string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(i, i)) + "\n";
    }
    return outPut;
}
```